# Autofac IComponentContext.Registrations is empty

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm having IDispatcher interface in my Core project:

```
public interface IDispatcher
{
    ...
}
```

And in Infrastructure project I'm having implementation:

```
public class AutofacDispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext container;

    public AutofacDispatcher(IComponentContext container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
        ...

}
```

Now when I'm calling:

```
var dispatcher = container.Resolve<IDispatcher>();
```

The private IComponentContext inside Dispatcher is empty and has no registrations.

Why is that and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself.

I had too many registrations in container (over 7k).

I managed to reference only my assemblies and now it's working.